# JavaScript while loop doesn't work with condition

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I have created function named `getIndex` *for get index which I search from the array.*

When I changed `while (1)` instead of `while (max < min)` that loop is working, but with condition (`while (max < min)`) it's return -1. But I need condition for check if my search is not present in `data` array. Why does it return -1 with condition?

```
// assume my array looks-like this.
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function getIndex(search, arr) {
    var min, max, guess, count;
    min = 0;
    max = arr.length - 1;
    count = 0;

    // If my search is not present in array. Return -1.
    while (max < min) {
        count++;
        guess = Math.floor((min + max) / 2);
        if (arr[guess] === search) {
            return guess;
        } else if (arr[guess] < search) {
            min = guess + 1;
        } else {
            max = guess - 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

getIndex(8, data); // return -1
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `data.indexOf(search)`?

Comment: why are you using a peculiar and worst way(in terms of time complexity) to search an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the while condition to `while(max>min)`

Answer (score 1):

You're doing mistake here .You're checking Max is less than min or not and above while loop you're setting min value to 0 and Max to length of array .Then how can Max be less than min ? It is doing right by not entering in the loop as condition is false. You need "min less than max" or "Max greater than min" (both serves the same purpose) in condition then it'll work fine .

Answer (score 1):

change the operation between the max and min in the while condition

```
 // assume my array looks-like this.
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10];
debugger;
function getIndex(search, arr) {
    var min, max, guess, count;
    min = 0;
    max = arr.length - 1;
    count = 0;

    // If my search is not present in array. Return -1.
    while (max > min) {
        count++;
        guess = Math.floor((min + max) / 2);
        if (arr[guess] === search) {
            return guess;
        } else if (arr[guess] < search) {
            min = guess + 1;
        } else {
            max = guess - 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

getIndex(8, data); // return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the for-loop, easier to understand

```js
// assume my array looks-like this.
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function getIndex(search, arr) {
    var guess = -1;
    // If my search is not present in array. Return -1.
 
 for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  if(arr[i]===search)guess = i;
 }
 return guess;
}

console.log(getIndex(8, data)); // return -1
```